# how do i implement the bisection method using this function prototype in C++

Tags: c++, bisection

```
double p1::root(double (*pf)(double k), int a, int b, double e)
```

im not sure how to go about it, i understand that i have to loop that pinpoints the midpoint and such

```
double p1::root(double (*pf)(double k), int a, int b, double e) {


  // void nrerror(char error_text[]);                                           
  int j;
  float dx, f, fmid, xmid, rtb;

  f = (*pf)(a);
  fmid = (*pf)(b);
  //if (f*fmid >= 0.0) nrerror("root must be bracketed for bisection in rtbis")\
;                                                                               
      rtb = f < 0.0 ? (dx=b-a,a) : (dx=a-b,b);
      for(j = 1;j <40; j++) {
        fmid = (*pf)(xmid = rtb+(dx *= .5));
      if (fmid <= 0.0) rtb = xmid;
      if (fabs(dx) < e || fmid == 0.0) return rtb;
      }
      // nrerror("too many bisections in rtbis");                               


  return 0.0;
}




double p1::test_function(double k) {
  return (pow(k, 3) -2);
}
```

then in main i have this

```
 double (*pf)(double k);
pf = &p1::test_function;

//double result = p1::root(pf, a, b, e);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [Numerical Recipes](http://www.aip.de/groups/soe/local/numres/bookcpdf/c9-1.pdf) will give you an idea.  Hint: it's recursive.

Comment: not soo much ill post what i have so far, it doesnt give me a result

Comment: "not soo much"?  The link I gave you has the method implemented right inside - rtbis.  Same signature and everything.

Comment: it did help, sorry for that reply, but what im trying to say is does it why dont you think it works with my implementation above

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking me.  The code you posted is from Numerical Recipes.  (It's licensed, by the way - you can't simply use it or hand it in as your own.)  Where's your code?  What does it do?

Comment: i understand, i just want to see how it works with my functions file and main file, after that i will make my own, in functions.cpp i have that function along with a test function, then in main i have the pointer

Comment: Link only answer and link is broken.